# How can I use SUM for bit columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

How can use the function SUM() for bit columns in T-SQL?

When I try do it as below:

```
SELECT SUM(bitColumn) FROM MyTable;
```

I get the error:

> Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: It depends on what you think a sum of a bit column is supposed to mean.  SQL Server doesn't allow it because it's ambiguous because bit columns are often boolean values or bitmasks.  It's like asking "What's the value of `Add(True,False)`?"  Well, is Add() an AND function or an OR function?

Comment: It's just a way to group results together. In my scenario one record has bitColumn True and other records have bitColumn False, but I don't want the grouping to be lost because of that. So I'm summing the "bit" columns and I'm interested if the SUM is greater than 0.

Comment: @BaconBits ADD usually translates to OR, and MULTIPLY to AND, because they follow similar laws

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez That's because that's how logic gates work where AND is a multiply and XOR is an add, not because that's the only meaningful interpretation of `SUM( <Boolean values> )`. It's certainly not clear enough to demand a specific implementation of `SUM()`.

Comment: Bits cannot be True or False.  Bits can only be 1 or 0.  Boolean can be True or False.  Summation of bits is not ambiguous. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_arithmetic

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(bitColumn AS INT))
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

need to cast into number

or another solution -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE bitColumn = 1
```

Comment: My query is in fact quite more complex than the example on my question. The bitColumn is coming from a joined table and my results are grouped. I  don't want to stop returning the results where bitColumn are False. But Solution 1 is perfect. So simple!

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT SUM(bitColumn * 1) FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Converts the bit into int, by multiplication, clean and simple

Comment: This seems to be the most simple and elegant solution among all.

Answer (score 22):

You could consider 0 as nulls and simply count the remaining values:

```
SELECT count(nullif(bitColumn, 0))
FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve by using `CONVERT`,

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, bitColumn)) FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 4):

My personal preference is a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN bitColumn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM MyTable;
```

Or, if you're really keen on code compression `IIF`.

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(bitColumn = 1, 1, 0)) FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`SIGN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql) function:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_x(b BIT);
INSERT INTO tab_x(b) VALUES(1),(0),(0),(NULL),(0),(1);

SELECT SUM(SIGN(b))
FROM tab_x;
-- 2
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6893d3a2c69d5a54f533d9a6b282dcb5)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use CAST and CONVERT function for data type to integer or number data type.

Try this code blocks :

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(bitColumn AS INT)) as bitColumn
FROM MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, bitColumn) 
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat cryptically:

```
declare @Foo as Bit = 1;
-- @Foo is a Bit.
select SQL_Variant_Property( @Foo, 'BaseType' );
-- But adding zero results in an expression with data type Int.
select SQL_Variant_Property( @Foo + 0, 'BaseType' );
select Sum( @Foo + 0 );

declare @Samples as Table ( Foo Bit );
insert into @Samples ( Foo ) values ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 0 ), ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 1 ), ( 1 ), ( 1 );
select Sum( Foo + 0 ) from @Samples;
```

This certainly doesn't improve readability or maintainability, but it is compact.